# Search Feature for Java EE Web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, search

I want to add a search feature (which will be working the same as the search feature of this stackoverflow website's search function) in my web application which is developed with Java EE .

Is it suitable to use the Nutch Search Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Web application can provide this search feature using Apache Nutch(for crawling) and Apache Solr for searching the crawled pages. If your web service needs to provide efficient and fast search then Nutch should run in a Hadoop cluster instead of a single machine. Hope this information helps.
Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched the web before posting a question?

The most clear choice would be [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). It is a widely used text-based indexing and searching facility with almost any feature you may want to have. It is completely based on Java and can be integrated well with your Java EE environment.